# How to cancel the update/create new installation when application is already installed

Tags: windows-installer, install4j

I am using install4j as an installer. I have installed my application and when I again execute the application_installer.exe to install my application, it ask for update/create new installation. But I want to exit if the application of same version is already installed. How can I do this in install4j installer?

Answer (score 1):

You can add a "Run script" action in the "Startup" node of the installer with the following script:

```
// The value returned by context.getInstallationDirectory() will be the last 
// installation directory if the user has already installed the application
ApplicationRegistry.ApplicationInfo applicationInfo =
   ApplicationRegistry.getApplicationInfoByDir(
     context.getInstallationDirectory()
);

if (applicationInfo == null) {
    // The application has never been installed before
    return true;
}

// The version of this installer is contained in a system installer variable
String myVersion = (String)context.getVariable("sys.version");
if (applicationInfo.getVersion().equals(myVersion)) {
    // In that case the current version is already installed.
    Util.showErrorMessage("The current version is already installed" + 
        " in this directory");
    // By returning "false", the action will fail and the installer will quit.
    // Note that you have to set the "Failure strategy" property of your
    // "Run script" action to "Quit on error", otherwise the installer will
    // continue.
    return false;
} else {
    return true;
}
```

This is an example script in the code gallery of the code editor.